# My sticky header causes the subsequent div to jump about 100 pixels when the navbar reaches the top of the page, can't figure out a fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As my title says, my sticky header is causing the subsequent div to jump about 100 pixels when the navbar reaches the top of the page. It's like the home div is magically losing 100 pixels of its height. I've tried a couple things but haven't been able to get this to work.

I have added plugins for smooth scrolling but couldn't get it to work in the jsfiddle. If you scroll down slowly when the navbar is getting to the top of the page, you will notice the skip.

Thanks for your help!

http://jsfiddle.net/g9N78/2/

here is the code I'm using for the sticky header:

```
<script>
    function moveScroller() {
        var move = function() {
            var st = $(window).scrollTop();
            var ot = $("#nav").offset().top;
            var s = $(".nav");
            if(st > ot) {
                s.css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: "0",
                    background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.65)"
                });   
            } else {
                if(st <= ot) {
                    s.css({
                        position: "",
                        top: "",
                        background: "black"
                    });
                } 
            }
        };
        $(window).scroll(move);
        move();
    }
</script> 



<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
    moveScroller();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are removing that object from the DOM flow the space is available and the element under takes it, you can just add some `margin` to `#home` like this:

> $('#home').css('marginTop','100px');

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/g9N78/3/

Comment: The `#nav` element in OT code is `90px` not `100px` Would remove the short blink.
Excelent answer though =)

Comment: You should set the margin value at the height of the bar finding the height through jQuery, the bar may render at different heights in different screen sizes and browsers.

Comment: This is the way to go @user3008011 I just use 100 as random value. But the OP can use the value that fits his needs. The main here is explain why this happen.

Comment: Yes, you are right, as the site is responsive though, it should be taken into consideration, just incase anything changes in height.

Comment: @Dijon that is a good point, do you have a link to an example that shows how to find the height of a div using jquery? thanks for your insight

Comment: @JoelLevy you can save it in another `var` check this http://jsfiddle.net/g9N78/7/

Comment: `var variableNameHere = $('.nav').height();`  However, I deleted my answer as I couldn't work out how to add it via `.css('marginTop',variableNameHere)` for some reason the fiddle wasn't working, maybe something I overlooked but certainly worth implementing if you can.

Comment: @danko just nailed it.

Comment: @Dijon you can't use the height of `#nav` since is the container of `.nav` and when .nav is fixed #nav heights=0. You need to check the height of `.nav` review the example in the comment before yours.

Comment: makes sense thats probably where I was going wrong. however your example just pulls the height from the css doesn't it? doesn't it need to be pulled dynamically from the element?

Comment: @Dijon you also have another problems in your fiddle I was comment about that and you remove the answer :P ... I remeber like  `body` isn't a valid element itself you need $('body').

Comment: I've updated my fiddle now, worked it out with @danko's help... http://jsfiddle.net/g9N78/8/

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery `.height()` method to find out the height of your nav bar, save it to a variable, then apply that height to the top margin of the page, to make it fill the space that the nav bar used to occupy.

`$(".nav").height();`

`$('#home').css('marginTop', navHeight);`

See the fiddle below...

http://jsfiddle.net/g9N78/8/

jQuery:

```
    function moveScroller() {
        var move = function() {
            var st = $(window).scrollTop();
            var ot = $("#nav").offset().top;
            var s = $(".nav"),
                navHeight = s.height();
            if(st > ot) {
                s.css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: "0",
                    background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.65)"
                });
                $('#home').css('marginTop', navHeight);
            } else {
                if(st <= ot) {
                    s.css({
                        position: "",
                        top: "",
                        background: "black"
                    });
                } 
                $('#home').css('marginTop', '0');
            }
        };
        $(window).scroll(move);
        move();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic involved. As long as you do not reach the scroll-top, the header is position:static. The following div will be displayed under the Top. As soon as the element is set to position: fixed, you "lose" the height of the header, causig the optical jump.
I don't think you need Javascript for your header to be sticky.

<s>Try removing the javascript and add this css:</s>

```
body
{
   padding-top: 90px;
}

.nav
{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0px;
   height: 90px;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Edit: Sorry I did not think about your Logo. So this will not work for you like that.